# Payment gateways/ processors for Japanese konbini (convenience store) payments

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway

The company I work for is currently using [Digital River](http://www.digitalriver.com/) to render a separate Japanese shopping cart on our e-commerce site.  We'd like to integrate Japanese payment options into our own cart app, but I am having trouble understanding konbini payments.  There is scant information about how to support convenience store payments.  Ideally I want a gateway like PayPal or cybersource.  Does anyone have any thoughts/experience with Konbini?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at Degica's [Komoju API documentation](http://docs.komoju.com/), which provides a full interface for creating payments on all major konbini chains. [Full disclosure: I work for Degica.]

The API is not public (yet) but if you are interested in using it or want more information you can contact [Degica](https://www.degica.com/contact/) directly. The system is very flexible in terms of customizing the konbini payment receipts, etc., and the API is clean and straightforward to use and includes other local payment options as well (wallets, bank transfer, etc.)